# Invisible attributes in tree view odoo

Tags: xml, odoo

I'm trying to hide some fields in my treeViews but it isn't working.
This my code :

```
<record id="partner_views_tree" model="ir.ui.view"> 
        <field name="name">partner.views.tree</field>
        <field name="type">tree</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_tree"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">

            <tree>
             <field name="phone" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="email" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="matricule"/>
                <field name="tel"/>
                <field name="email_no"/>
                <field name="annee_prestation"/>

            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
```

I don't know how to hide fields, is there a way to do this? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
<record id="partner_views_tree" model="ir.ui.view"> 
     <field name="name">partner.views.tree</field>
     <field name="type">tree</field>
     <field name="model">res.partner</field>
     <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_tree"/>
     <field name="arch" type="xml">
         <xpath expr="//field[@name='phone']" position="attributes">
             <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
         </xpath>
         <xpath expr="//field[@name='email']" position="attributes">
             <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
         </xpath>
     </field>
 </record>
```

Answer (score 2):

When we want to hide any parent view field then we should use following mechanism.

Try with these:

```
<field name="phone" position="atrributes">
    <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
</field>
```